# DoctrineSelect with Variable

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I'm trying something like this with doctrine:

```
SELECT 
    @myprice := cp.price,
    @compPrice1 := (SELECT cpt1.price FROM competitor_product AS cpt1 
                    WHERE cpt1.product_id = cp.product) as compPrice1 
    @compPrice1 / @myprice  AS price_diff
FROM
    customer_product AS cp 
WHERE 
    customer_id = 1;
```

My code until then:

[my code until then][image: 1]

How can I set variable for use in calculate column?

I've been looking for but found nothing about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with Doctrine Query builder. I would suggest use [Doctrine Native Query](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/native-sql.html)  or Raw SQL queries.